# React-Native - Fetch Post Request Fails (Android)

Tags: javascript, php, react-native

I have this PHP:

```
<?php

  include('connect.php');

  $data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
  $statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM M_Messages where M_B_Id = " . $data->blogId);
  $statement->execute();
  $Messages = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);


  $statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM B_Blogs where B_Id = " . $data->blogId);
  $statement->execute();
  $Blog = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

  echo json_encode(array("Messages" => $Messages, "Blog" => $Blog));
?>
```

This is my fetch call React-Native:

```
var formData = {
        'blogId': this.state.blogId
    };

   fetch('http://www.bloggaa.co.uk/getMessagesByBlogId.php', {
          method: 'POST',
          headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          },
          body: JSON.stringify(formData)
        })
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((responseJson) => {

            //alert(responseJson.Messages);
            //this.setState({
                //dataSource:this.state.ds.cloneWithRows(responseJson.Messages),
                //blogTitle: responseJson.Blog[0].B_Title,
            //  });


      })
      .catch((error) => {
        alert('ddddd ' + error.message);
      });
```

Im typing in the url: 
http://xxxxxx.co.uk/getMessagesByBlogId.PHP?blogId=1

But i get returned:
{"Messages":[],"Blog":[]}

And React-Native is returning a JSON parse error Unrecognized token '<'

I have managed to get the 'GET' request working but no luck with the Post Method.

Can someone help please?

Comment: Try logging the response variable before calling .json() on it, and double check it is valid JSON.

Comment: @MartinKonicek i get html its a bit long but it includes the text GOOGLEBOT in the meta tag in capitols, any clues?

Comment: It looks like your webserver is returning HTML instead of JSON. Are you hitting the correct endpoint?

Comment: @MartinKonicek. Yes im hitting the correct endpoint, the get method works fine its just when i Post data